# Finding the minimums of groups of observations in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I'm relatively new to R and struggle with "vectorizing" all my code in R. Even though I appreciate that's the proper way to do it.

I need to set a value in a dataframe to be the minimum time for the IDs.

```
ID  isTrue  RealTime  MinTime
1    TRUE     16
1    FALSE    8
1    TRUE     10
2    TRUE     7
2    TRUE     30
3    FALSE    3
```

To be turned into:

```
ID  isTrue  RealTime  MinTime
1    TRUE     16        10
1    FALSE    8         
1    TRUE     10        10
2    TRUE     7         7
2    TRUE     30        7
3    FALSE    3
```

The following works perfectly. However, it takes 10 minutes to run which isn't ideal:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){

    if (df[i,'isTrue']) {
      prevTime <- sqldf(paste('Select min(MinTime) from dfStageIV where ID =',df[i,'ID'],sep=" "))[1,1]
      if  (is.na(prevTime) | is.na(df[i,'MinTime']) | df[i,'MinTime'] < prevTime){
        df[i,'MinTime']<-dfStageIV[i,'RealTime']
      } else {
        dfStageIV[i,'MinTime']<-prevTime
      }
    }
}
```

How should I do this properly? I take it using for or do loops are not the best way in R. I've been looking at the apply() and aggregate.data.frame() functions but can't make sense of how to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction? Much appreciated!!

Comment: Take a look at `ave`.

Comment: Thanks, first try was close. df$MinTime<-ave(df$RealTime,df$ID, FUN = min). But how do I only get it to take the ones where isTrue = TRUE?

Comment: df$MinTime<-ave(df$RealTime,df$ID, df$isTrue, FUN = min)
df$MinTime<-ifelse(df$isTrue, df$MinTime,NA). This returns a ton of warnings but works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone suggested using the ave() function and the following works and is fast although it returns a ton of warnings:

```
df$MinTime<-ave(df$RealTime,df$ID, df$isTrue, FUN = min) 
df$MinTime<-ifelse(df$isTrue, df$MinTime,NA).
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a two line base R solution using `ave`, `pmax`, and `is.na`.

```
# calculate minimum for each ID, excluding FALSE instances
df$MinTime <- ave(pmax(df$RealTime, (!df$isTrue) * max(df$RealTime)), df$ID, FUN=min)
# turn FALSE instances into NA
is.na(df$MinTime) <- (!df$isTrue)
```

which returns

```
df
  ID isTrue RealTime MinTime
1  1   TRUE       16      10
2  1  FALSE        8      NA
3  1   TRUE       10      10
4  2   TRUE        7       7
5  2   TRUE       30       7
6  3  FALSE        3      NA
```

In the first line, `pmax` is used to construct a vector of the observations if `df$isTrue` is TRUE or the maximum RealTime value in the data.frame. This new vector is used in the minimum calculation. The FALSE values are set to NA in the second line.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="ID  isTrue  RealTime
1    TRUE     16
1    FALSE    8
1    TRUE     10
2    TRUE     7
2    TRUE     30
3    FALSE    3")
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be far faster with a `dplyr` chain. Here we group the data frame by both ID and group and get the minima at the group level. Then we can ungroup it again and simply remove the `F` minima.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID, isTrue) %>% 
   mutate(Min.all = min(RealTime)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>%
   transmute(ID, isTrue, RealTime, MinTime = ifelse(isTrue == T, Min.all, ""))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
     ID isTrue RealTime MinTime
  <int>  <lgl>    <int>   <chr>
1     1   TRUE       16      10
2     1  FALSE        8        
3     1   TRUE       10      10
4     2   TRUE        7       7
5     2   TRUE       30       7
6     3  FALSE        3
```

I'd really recommend you get familiar with `dplyr` if you're going to be doing lots of data frame manipulation.

Comment: Thank you. I'll dive into the dplyr library since it looks quite helpful. As I posted below from someone else's suggestion, the ave() function worked for this as well grouping by ID and isTrue

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question could be simplified by doing it all in SQL or all in R (appropriately vectorized) rather than half and half.  There are already some R solutions so here is an SQL solution that shows that the problem amounts to aggregating a custom self-join.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.*, min(b.RealTime) minRealTime
       from df a 
       left join df b on a.ID = b.ID and a.isTRUE and b.isTRUE
       group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  ID isTrue RealTime minRealTime
1  1   TRUE       16          10
2  1  FALSE        8          NA
3  1   TRUE       10          10
4  2   TRUE        7           7
5  2   TRUE       30           7
6  3  FALSE        3          NA
```